# An upper bound for the tree width of the strong product of 2 graphs

Tags: graph-theory

In the paper [Product structure of graphs with an excluded minor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.06627.pdf), the authors used the below inequality in many places without proving it.

$$tw(G \boxtimes K _{\lfloor m \rfloor} ) \leq (tw(G) + 1).m − 1$$

And in general

$$tw(G1 \boxtimes G2) \leq (tw(G1) + 1).|V(G2)| − 1$$

It seems like a well-known inequality, I would appreciate it if someone could guide me to its proof. Thank you.

Comment: One thing we can say without too much thought is that if $|V(G_2)|=m$, then $G_1 \boxtimes G_2$ is a subgraph of $G_1 \boxtimes K_m$, so $tw(G_1 \boxtimes G_2) \le tw(G_1 \boxtimes K_m)$. Therefore the first inequality implies the second.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! Indeed I am looking for a proof to one of those 2 inequalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One characterization of the treewidth of a graph $G$ is as follows. The value $tw(G)+1$ is the minimum clique number of any [chordal completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_completion) of $G$: the minimum clique number of any chordal graph $H$ such that $G$ is a subgraph of $H$.

To prove the first inequality, let $H$ be any chordal completion of $G$ with clique number $tw(G)+1$. Then $H \boxtimes K_m$ is a chordal completion of $G \boxtimes K_m$, and has clique number $(tw(G)+1) \cdot m$. We are not guaranteed that $H \boxtimes K_m$ has the smallest clique number of all chordal completions of $G \boxtimes K_m$, so all we can say is that $(tw(G)+1) \cdot m$ is an upper bound on $tw(G \boxtimes K_m) + 1$; in other words, $$tw(G \boxtimes K_m) \le (tw(G)+1) \cdot m - 1.$$

The second inequality has the same proof: just use the fact that if $H$ is a chordal completion of $G_1$ and $|V(G_2)| = m$, then $H \boxtimes K_m$ is a chordal completion of $G_1 \boxtimes G_2$.

Comment: thanks :) may I ask for more clarification concerning the statement "Then, $H \boxtimes K _{\lfloor m \rfloor}$ is a chordal completion of $G \boxtimes K _{\lfloor m \rfloor}$" - is it a theorem that needs to be proved or more like simple reasoning?

Comment: Well, it depends on how much detail you want to go into. It is straightforward that $G \boxtimes K_m$ is a subgraph of $H \boxtimes K_m$. It is not so straightforward that $H \boxtimes K_m$ is chordal - essentially, if you look for chordless cycles of length $>3$ in $H \boxtimes K_m$, they'd have to be taking a step in $H$ as well as a step in $K_m$ all the way around, so they'd have to come from chordless cycles in $H$, which by assumption do not exist.