# How to show that every graph $G$ is a minor of $T \boxtimes K_k$, where $k=tw(G)+1$?

Tags: graph-theory

##### Question

How to show that for every graph $G$, there exists a tree $T$ such that $G$ is a minor of $T \boxtimes K_k$ where $k = tw(G) + 1$.

##### Notations

1. $tw$ stands for [treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth).
2. $\boxtimes$ stands for the [Strong Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829436/an-upper-bound-for-the-tree-width-of-the-strong-product-of-2-graphs)

Note that the following inequality is true: $tw(T \boxtimes K_k) ≤ 2k − 1$ (see [An upper bound for the tree width of the strong product of 2 graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829436/an-upper-bound-for-the-tree-width-of-the-strong-product-of-2-graphs)). It might be useful but I am not sure!

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Do you have any context?

Comment: it's an exercise in an introduction to graph theory course, where the first part of the exercise is the linked question, and this question is the second and last part.